# Flutter: > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I bought a source cade from Codecanyon which i have been trying to set it up on my Mac os using Android studio... i have experienced alot of issues and have been able to solve some of them by upgrading my flutter version, switching to flutter master channel, installing jdk8 and running pub get

Now i tried running the code and it was stuck on "Running Gradle task assembledebug" so someone suggested i run  `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease` from the "android" directory, which i did and it downloaded alot of thing then when it got to "Executing" it stopped at 2% with some error which i solve by changing the "compileSdkVersion" from 30 to "compileSdkVersion 31" now when i run the code again it stops at executing at 4% with the error bellow

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s
20 actionable tasks: 20 up-to-date

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
 - TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State<InternalSelectableMath>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1034:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
  void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1014:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
  void cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1022:16: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText' is defined here.
  Future<void> pasteText(SelectionChangedCause cause);
               ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1028:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll' is defined here.
  void selectAll(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^


> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/bright/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1100

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/bright/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

when i run "flutter doctor -v" i get the details down bellow

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.6.0-12.0.pre.719, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-NG)
    • Flutter version 2.6.0-12.0.pre.719 at /Users/bright/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 34dbee66de (3 days ago), 2021-11-14 18:46:02 -0500
    • Engine revision 140bd9399e
    • Dart version 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-10.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.8.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/bright/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/bright/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

i checked some similar question here and their answers was to run "pub get" which i have run countless of times now and still nothing is changing

***UPDATE***

When i run `Flutter run` from the project folder i get just this error bellow

```
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
 - TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State<InternalSelectableMath>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1034:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
  void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1014:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
  void cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1022:16: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText' is defined here.
  Future<void> pasteText(SelectionChangedCause cause);
               ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1028:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll' is defined here.
  void selectAll(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/bright/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1100

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/bright/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 41s
```

Comment: What is the version of your gradle in project? You can see in android>gradle>wrapper>gradlew-wrapper.properties, in distributionUrl.

Comment: And what are you using a pre-release version 2.6? Why you don't use a stable? Was the orientation to run the code?

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo the gradlw version i am running it on currently is `gradle-6.3-all.zip`... but it was initially on `gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`. but due to some errors i had to move it to 6.3